# How to assign a role to a user depending on order subtotal using Ubercart?

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart

I am using ubercart in drupal 7 . I need to assign a role to user after checkout. For this I created a rule using checkout complete. 
But I need to assign a role depend on order subtotal. this option is not meeting me on rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use that "*Order subtotal*" in a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***Condition***", you could try to first add a Rules condition `Entity has field` (related to the field containing that "*Order subtotal*").

That's also what is mentioned in the Rules UI when you're adding a "data comparison" condition, somewhere it says:

> *The data selector helps you drill down into the data available to [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). To make entity fields appear in the data selector, you may have to use the condition 'entity has field' (or 'content is of type')*.

So if you don't have an appropriate "field" for it, then you may be able to get it to work also by using that 'content is of type'.

For a video tutorial that illustrates the importance of this `Entity has field` condition, refer to [Data types and data selection](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/data-types-and-data-selection), especially what is shown between about 13:30 and 17:30 in it.